# Vue.js view model and splitting in different files

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Although everything works fine in a single file. I am having trouble to split the code in multiple files and then bundling in a .vue file. Here i am giving the final .vue file for simplicity.

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Using databinding with components</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is databinding</h1>
<databinding></databinding>

<script src="build/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My js file

```
//databindingcomponent.js
var Vue = require('vue')
var Databinding = require('./components/databinding/databinding.vue')

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        databinding: Databinding
    }
})
```

my vue file (./components/databinding/databinding.vue)

```
<template>
<div id="example1">
    Hello {{ name }}, the date is {{ date }}!
</div></template>

<script>
var Vue = require('vue')

var exampleData = {
    name: 'Vue.js',
    date: '2016-07-13'
}

// create a Vue instance, or, a "ViewModel"
// which links the View and the Model
var exampleVM = new Vue({
    el: '#example1',
    data: exampleData
})</script>
```

And then i run

```
.\node_modules\.bin\browserify -t vueify -e .\databindingcomponent.js -o .\build\bundle.js
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
databindingcomponent.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(anonymous function) @ databindingcomponent.js:2
```

Here is the code in a single file (it works but I want to split it into .html and .js and use final .vue file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example1">
    Hello {{ name }}, the date is {{ date }}!
</div>

<script>
    var exampleData = {
        name: 'Vue.js',
        date: '2016-07-13'
    }

    // create a Vue instance, or, a "ViewModel"
    // which links the View and the Model
    var exampleVM = new Vue({
        el: '#example1',
        data: exampleData
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Require will not be defined if you don't include a module loader.